# Ansible Ping hangs after first machine

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have 3 VMs:

- ansible-host: 192.168.0.103
- app1: 192.168.0.105
- app2: 192.168.0.106

Now I have verified that doing `ssh -i ansible_id_rsa vagrant@192.168.0.105` works for app1 and same for app2.

I defined an inventory.yml file with the following content:

```
app:
  hosts:
    vm01:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.105
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa
    vm02:
      ansible_host: 192.168.0.106
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa
```

After this, I try to run `ansible app -i inventory.yml -m ping` but it hangs after returning success message for first machine, and pressing enter brings up the red error text as below.

[image: 1]

When I run it with `-vvvv`, I notice this line where it says `read header failed: Broken pipe`. Currently it seems to fail for app2 but if I remove app1 from inventory file, I get success message for app2 as well.

What might be going wrong here?

Update:

Internally, it runs the below command and this is what throws Broken pipe error but not really sure what to do about it.

```
ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/home/vagrant/.ssh/ansible_id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o Prefe
rredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/3605020054"' 192.168.0
.105 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1661084339.4252737-8700-269402406490478/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Update 2:

So I was suggested to add a few properties to the ansible.cfg file which now looks like this:

```
[ssh_connection] 
host_key_checking=no 
pipelining=yes 
ssh_args=-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=10m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

With this:

- first time after startup, it passes for first machine and then fails for second specifying an issue about python interpreter
- every time after that, it works for all

Specifying the python intepreter anywhere however (anisble.cfg or inventory.yml) makes it fail for all but first machine everytime.

Not really sure why this happens!

Comment: Found out that adding symlinks for /user/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3 atleast makes it successful every time but it still hangs until propted. So it could be a python version based issue.

Comment: Use a passwordless key or add the key to your ssh agent. Adding master session works the second time because first connection is already opened and you just have to create the second. Ansible is not made to handle interactive input unless its own (like the `-K` command line parameter...). In you initial setup, you would actually have to enter the password and press enter for each host in your play loop (if that could work at all...)

Comment: @Zeitounator, I updated the private key to have an empty passphrase and used the `-K` flag. Now it does execute all at once but still does ask for the escalation password. Anyway I can prevent that?
Instead `-b` works and doesn't ask for any passwords either. 
What do you think is the better practice and what could I improve in this setup?

Comment: Add the escalation password to your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zeitounator, the solution was to:

1. Either use a password-less ssh key or add the password to ssh-agent
2. Use `-K` and add become password to inventory file from vault or use `-b` to escalate privileges without password

Doing this makes it run in one go without stopping or prompting inputs.

Comment: Well you can provide username and password to ansible and even secure said username and password in a vault.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard yes, so when we want to use -K, I mentioned using vault so as to not store it as plaintext in source control